# Laravel link preview in Telegram

Tags: php, html, laravel, .htaccess, seo

I have two Laravel  sites, both are the same, but on my second site the preview link is not displayed
I put the og tags directly in the header and directly set them the address of the image, I even dynamically add addressed them from within the controller and added the address of the images to open graph.

But problem was not solved.

I used slug for the site address, but the problem is that it does not show the first page of the site
my site URL is this
https://exampl.com/blogshow/news-break
may be change htaccess to work it?

A friend said that the slug is characters make it with id example https://example.com/posts/1122 ,
I used the SEO tools package and completed its configuration correctly, but there is still a problem
Of course, link preview in phone text messages (SMS)  displayed correctly , only in Telegram  a problem
And of course, the site is new, it has been uploaded for 2 months, maybe it has something to do with Google's index?
Please advise

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.